# Regex to match a timer with h:m:s

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been working on matching a variable from a client. It reads as such:

```
0s
12s
1m15s
15m0s
1h0m5s
1h15m17s
```

I would like to capture all three groupings of digits within a single find.

```
(\d+)(?=h(\d+)m(\d+))*?(?=m(\d+))*?
```

The regex I have been working on above however will only grab the successive groups in each new find.

example:

```
input is 12s group 1 is 12 ... works.
```

input is 1m12s group 1 is 1 however to get the 12, I have to use find                         again to get to the next group of 12.

Just as note as it didn't occur to me right away, make sure to do a check if a group is null for capturing groups that are optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

```
((\d+)h)?((\d+)m)?((\d+)s)
```

Then you capture group 2 for hour, group 4 for minutes and group 6 for seconds

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/bZ4zW4/2

In a graphical way:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/l5JCO2LeYYKjpfuu)

**EDIT**

To get the results in JAVA (since your last edit) do as follow:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\d+)h)?((\\d+)m)?((\\d+)s)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("1h15m17s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer hour = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
    Integer minute = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(hour + " - " + minute + " - " + second);
}

m = p.matcher("1h0m5s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer hour = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
    Integer minute = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(hour + " - " + minute + " - " + second);
}

m = p.matcher("15m0s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer minute = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4));
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(minute + " - " + second);
}

m = p.matcher("12s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(second);
}

m = p.matcher("0s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(second);
}
```

The output will be respectively:

```
1 - 15 - 17
1 - 0 - 5
15 - 0
12
0
```

Note that in each case I'm getting a specific value. If you try to get a minute from a `matcher` that is nonexistent you will get a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` because it will return null. So you must check it first. This below block will end up in the mentioned exception:

```
m = p.matcher("0s");
if (m.find()){
    Integer minute = Integer.valueOf(m.group(4)); //exception here
    Integer second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(6));
    System.out.println(second);
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear here, you need to get those groups with java?

Comment: I had to do a check if the group was null since the regex uses optional on the groups. That was the part I didn't realize. Got it now, and this regex worked as expected.